# Python parse int from string

Tags: python

```
test1 = 'name1'
test2 = 'name2'
..
test3 = 'name45'
test4 = 'name1231231'
```

Let's say I have bunch of strings which start with 'name' and are followed by a number of any length.

How can I parse out the number in the string?

Is `regex` the only way or is there a built-in module that can accomplish this task?

Comment: I did not downvote but perhaps your post was downvoted because of one of these [reasons](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Umcsc.png)

Comment: Loop over all of them, replace `name` and cast `int()` or `float()` on them.

Comment: int_testi=int(testi[4:len(testi)]) would do.

Comment: its pretty clear, and there is research via regex, how is it not useful? this can be helpful to others

Comment: If you have the strings like this `test=['name1','name2','name123125']` you can get just the integers like this: `ints = [int(n[4:]) for n in test]`

Comment: this question is different from someone marking as duplicate. this has a specific format of numbers being the last and finding ways to do it and the answered regex wont work in this format

Comment: @karthikr : it is not the same.

Comment: @karthikr remove duplicate if you agree

Comment: The idea is the same you just need a boundary for end of pattern.. But yes, the answer provided is better - so removed the dup mark

Comment: How about [Extract Number from String - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26825729) or [How to get integer values from a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11339210)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Python 3, you could do the following:

```
import string

for test in ['name1', 'name2', 'name45', 'name1231231', '123test']:
    print(int(test.strip(string.ascii_letters)))
```

Giving you:

```
1
2
45
1231231
123
```

`string.ascii_letters` gives you a string containing all upper and lowercase letters. Python's [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) function takes a string specifying the set of characters to be removed, which in this case is all alpha characters, thus leaving just the numbers behind.

Note: This would not be suitable for a string such as `123name456`.

---

If there are just known common prefixes/suffixes to all strings, the following approach could also be used in Python 3.9:

```
for test in ['name1', 'name2', 'name45', 'name1231231', '123test']:
    print(test.removeprefix('name').removesuffix('test'))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know that the prefix is `name`, then you can either remove just that string, or you can skip the first four letters, like so:

```
s = 'name123'
print int(s.replace('name',''))

s = 'name123'
print int(s[4:])
```