# Parsing dates from txt file as integers

Tags: python, parsing, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-science

My source is txt file which takes the form of:

```
cpu95-20000117-04004,134.perl,42.6,44.4
cpu95-20000117-04004,147.vortex,44.7,44.7
```

I would like to parse the date with python into a form that can be plotted with `matplotlib.pyplot` (i.e. no strings or Timestamp objects).
I will plot the last item (i.e. 44.4) against the dates (i.e. 2000/01/17).
I'm also using this data as an input for `scikitlearn linear regression model` later on so I believe it should be `int` or `float`. Thanks much.

PS - I checked similar questions, but the trend is to use either `.date()` method or panda's `pd.to_datetime` and its variations, or methods that produce sorts of objects that don't fit into `scikit model` or `matplotlib`.

**EDIT**
I should be more clear: I would like to plot the `real dates` (so no `toordinal`), and therefore cannot use the datetime option (wouldn't work for `pyplot` and `scikit`, when trying to turn `datetime` to `int`); therefore, I probably need to find a way to treat something like 2000/01/17 or 2000.01.17 as an integer.

Comment: Have you looked up __[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib)__? Why would you fit a model with a date like that? The common practice is to use indices. Assume that `2000:01:17` is the initial period point that equals 1. Then, the next period would be equal to 2, and so on. There is no way you can treat `2000/01/17` or `2000.01.17` as `int` object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can use an integer representation of the years and a float value for the last items in the lines as inputs to scikit this should do what you want.

`toordinal` returns something called the 'proleptic' for the date. This means that the 1st of January in the year 1 is represented by 1, January 2 becomes 2, etc. Which works fine for ordinary regression.

`re.search` winkles out the two pieces you need from the input lines for further processing.

Three lists are compiled as the for-loop progresses. `Y` eventually contains the final items in the input lines, `dates_for_plotting` the dates as needed by matplotlib and `dates_for_regression` the integer values as needed for your regression.

The last part of script shows how to use the dates as gathered from the input to create a plot.

```
>>> txt = '''\
... cpu95-20000117-04004,134.perl,42.6,44.4
... cpu95-20000117-04004,147.vortex,44.7,44.7
... '''
>>> import re
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> Y = []
>>> dates_for_plotting = []
>>> dates_for_regression = []
>>> for line in txt.split('\n'):
...     if line:
...         r = re.search(r'-([^-]+)-(?:[^,]+,){3}([0-9.]+)', line).groups()
...         the_date = datetime.strptime(r[0], '%Y%m%d')
...         dates_for_plotting.append(the_date.date())
...         dates_for_regression.append(the_date.toordinal())
...         Y.append(r[1])
...         
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import matplotlib.dates as mdates
>>> plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
>>> plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
>>> plt.plot(dates_for_plotting, Y)
>>> plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
>>> plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you probably have to write your own small parser.

You can use regular expressions, or use line.split(',') on every line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the number in int().

Example:

```
myString = "20000117"
try:
    myVar = int(myString)
except ValueError:
    pass # or take some action here
```

[Python parse int from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993549/python-parse-int-from-string)

Wrap it in a try block to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for if I understood your question correctly :)

```
with open("YourFileName.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        #line = "cpu95-20000117-04004,134.perl,42.6,44.4"
        items = line.split(',') # [cpu95-20000117-04004,134.perl,42.6,44.4]

        date = int(items[0].split('-')[1])
        lastItem = float(items[-1])
        # rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but you can try like this

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    dt = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in dt:
        date = int(row[0][6:14])
        value = float(row[3])
```