# Is there a build-in function of Python to get the number of a string?

Tags: python

Is there a build-in function of Python to get the number of a string?

I have a type of string like this `'20180318_beta'`.

I want to get the `20180318` of it, so is there a build-in method for achieving this?

Comment: this will do int(filter(str.isdigit, str1)) from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825729/extract-number-from-string-in-python/26825781)

Comment: If it's always number followed by underscore, do `int(mystring.split("_")[0])`

Comment: @NidhinSajeev: This assumes no digit are separated from the main block of numbers required (a string like `'20180318_beta2'` would be parsed as `201803182`, which is probably not the intention). Also, using `filter` (without wrapping with `''.join()` to convert the `filter` iterator back to a `str`) will only work on Python 2.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ok but here he want to Extract numbers from a string only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of built in functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

As you can see, there is no specific function for what you are asking. However, if you wanted to build a function for it, there are many questions you have to ask yourself. Can it handle negatives? Can you find non-integers? What about numbers in different places?

You can always use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to attempt this problem. Here is a previous post about it: [Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

If all of your cases will be similar to the one above, you can always use the [split](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) method. In other cases, I would refer to this post: [Extract Number from String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825729/extract-number-from-string-in-python/26825781)

Just as a side note, if you do use the last link, be careful with the top answer with Python 3.x as the filter function is slightly different than its counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on the robustness you require, casting to int will work in this case because your string starts with numbers. However, If it started with a letter it would fail.

It's pretty simple to roll your own, see this stack overflow answer.

[Python parse int from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993549/python-parse-int-from-string)

Comment: "Casting" to `int` won't work; `int('20180318_beta')` will raise a `ValueError`; `int` is for strings composed solely of valid digits, with optional leading and trailing whitespace (which is ignored).