# how can i extract the numbers from the output of subprocess.check_output method

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

please i have a problem with the output of subprocess.check_output method ,
i want to extract just the numbers from its output!!
this is my code and the output is the picture below :

```
disply = subprocess.check_output('grgsm_scanner -p36' , shell=True).splitlines()
print disply
```

this is the output data :
[image for returned data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BITeg.png)

how can i get just the numbers from for example disply[2] and disply[3]....etc
in other term i want all numbers in the data of output , i want to get for example : [24 , 939.8 , 46021 ,461, 603 ,2 ,-27,......]
with number format not string ,
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Number from String - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825729/extract-number-from-string-python)

Comment: It is better to just post the text in your question rather than posting *pictures* of text.  Can you be more specific about what you want to extract?  The value in `disply[2]` has more than a single number in iit. Do you just want a list of numbers? Do you need to preserve the tags?  **Update your question** to show what you want the final values to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **re** module in python

```
import re 
re.findall(r'\d+',display[2])
re.findall(r'\d+',display[3])
```

That would extract all the numeric values.

Comment: Thank you pankaj mishra , but this method return the string not number , i want to get a number format

Comment: can you show me what it is returning at your end , the output is supposed to be numeric only