# Looping through string to only append integers to list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, loops, int

I am just trying to get this done for a project I am doing. I want to jsu parse/loop through a string of letters and numbers but I would like to just add the numbers to a list and convert them to integers.

```
x = "hello123"
myList = []
def func():
    for i in x:  
        if int in mylist:
            print(mylist)
            i = int(i)
            myList.append(i)
func()
```

I just need it to add the 123 to a list and make them integers.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47623382/9209546) using `str.isdigit` in the linked duplicate may help.

Comment: It is ambiguous, what your expected output is. Do you want to append 1, 2, and 3 or 123? What should happen in the case of ``hello123kitty321woof123`?

Comment: @Mr.T I would like it to be 1,2,3 and in the case of   `x = "hello123kitty321woof123"` i would like it to be the same

Comment: @jpp thank you for that I want something a little different but I can mess around with it.

Comment: So if you want to add each digit only once to your list, why don't you test, if the string contains 0, 1, 2,...,9? if str(0) in x: mylist.append(0).