# How do I extract the number at the beginning of a string in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numbers

I'm using Python 3.7.  I'm having difficulty extractng a number from teh beginning of a string.  The string is derived from an HTML element, like so

```
elt.text
'3 reviews'
```

However, when I try and get the number using logic here -- [Extract Number from String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825729/extract-number-from-string-in-python/26825781) , I get the error below

```
int(filter(str.isdigit, elt.text))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'filter'
```

Is there a better way to get the number from the beginning of the string?

Comment: `filter` returns an iterator, not just the number you are looking for. You cannot cast a `filter` to an `int`. The error is saying `int() argument must not be a 'filter' object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments on that answer note, in Python 3, `filter` returns a filter generator object, so you must iterate over it and build a new string before you can call `int`:

```
>>> s = '3 reviews'
>>> filter(str.isdigit, s)
<filter object at 0x800ad5f98>
>>> int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, s)))
3
```

However, as other answers in that same thread point out, this is not necessarily a good way to do the job at all:

```
>>> s = '3 reviews in 12 hours'
>>> int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, s)))
312
```

It might be better to use a regular expression matcher to find the number at the front of the string.  You can then decide whether to allow signs (`+` and `-`) and leading white-space:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match(r'\s*([-+])?\d+', s)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='3'>
>>> m.group()
'3'
>>> int(m.group())
3
```

Now if your string contains a malformed number, `m` will be None, and if it contains a sign, the sign is allowed:

```
>>> m = re.match(r'\s*([-+])?\d+', 'not a number')
>>> print(m)
None
>>> m = re.match(r'\s*([-+])?\d+', '  -42')
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='  -42'>
>>> int(m.group())
-42
```

If you wish to inspect what came after the number, if anything, add more to the regular expression (including some parentheses for grouping) and use `m.group(1)` to get the matched number.  Replace `\d+` with `\d*` to allow an empty number-match, if that's meaningful (but then be mindful of matching a lone `-` or `+` sign, if you still allow signs).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way if the number is always at the beginning of the string, given it's a single digit:

```
number = int(elt.text[0])
```

Or for more than one digit:

```
number = int(elt.text.split()[0])
```

Comment: This would work assuming the character after the number is a space. It probably is but this wouldn't work in a case like `elt.text = "34x"`

Comment: True, just giving a simple approach if the format is expected to be the same in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can amend the top answer in the link you send to this:

```
str1 = "3158 is a great number"
print(int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, str1))))
#3158
```

As to why the answer doesn't work now, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

there's a more intuitive way to do it. I'll make an assumption and think that there's a posibility that in a given string more than one number will appear. So, you want to iterate the words of the input.

```
numbers = [int(s) for s in input_string.split(' ') if s.isdigit()]
```

The first element of the list is the first number found on the given string, it is available by taking it out of the list `numbers[0]`.

If you are certain and there's not a chance that the first 'element' of the input string isn't anything else but a number, you can just split the string by spaces (or the separator you are using) and cast it to an `integer` or `float`.

```
int(input_string.split(' ')[0]) or float(input_string.split(' ')[0])
```

If you aren't certain, wrap it into a `try` and take the response either of the succesful `try` or the `except`.