# separate number from the string

Tags: python

the separate number from the string, but when successive '1', separate them

I think there must have a smart way to solve the question.

```
s = 'NNNN1234N11N1N123'
```

expected result is:

```
['1234','1','1','1','123']
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `['1234','1','1','123']` instead of `['1234','1','1','23']`?

Comment: you are right, sorry for that, I have changed it.

Comment: re.findall("\d+", i): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825729/extract-number-from-string-in-python/26825781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want can be solved by using the `re` module

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('(?:1[2-90]+)|1', 'NNNN1234N11N1N123')
```

**EDIT**: As suggested in the comments by @CrafterKolyan the regular expression can be reduced to `1[2-90]*`.

Outputs

```
['1234', '1', '1', '1', '123']
```

Comment: Thank you , I'm not familiar with re, I will study your code, appreciate it, THX.

Comment: Well, take a look into regular expressions (and the `re` module of course), they are very useful!

Comment: Yeah. I will. I reedit the question, forgot something, Thank you.

Comment: I fixed the regular expression, so the result is as expected.

Comment: Regex can be easier `1[2-90]*`

Comment: re.findall('(1[2-90]+)|1', 'NN1234**12222311*1112N12311NN123456**1222')     return  ['1234', '122223', '', '', '', '', '12', '123', '', '', '123456', '1222']    '1' is missing. What happend :)

Comment: I think you missed the `(?:`

Answer (score 0):

I also would use regular expressions (`re` module), but other function, namely `re.split` following way:

```
import re
s = 'NNNN1234N11N1N123'
output = re.split(r'[^\d]+|(?<=1)(?=1)',s)
print(output) # ['', '1234', '1', '1', '1', '123']
output = [i for i in output if i] # jettison empty strs
print(output) # ['1234', '1', '1', '1', '123']
```

Explanation: You want to split `str` to get `list` of `str`s - that is for what `re.split` is used. First argument of `re.split` is used to tell where split should happen, with everything which will be matched being removed if capturing groups are not used (similar to `str` method `split`), so I need to specify two places where cut happen, so I used `|` that is alternative and informed `re.split` to cut at:

- `[^\d]+` that is 1 or more non-digits
- `(?<=1)(?=1)` that is empty `str` preceded by `1` and followed by `1`, here I used feature named zero-length assertion (twice)

Note that `re.split` produced `''` (empty `str`) before your desired output - this mean that first cut (`NNNN` in this case) spanned from start of `str`. This is expected behavior of `re.split` although we do not need that information in this case so we can jettison any empty `str`s, for which I used `list` comprehension.