# Extract roman numerals from string in python

Tags: python, string, split, roman-numerals

I have a list of strings, containing chords represented as Latin Numerals like this:

```
['ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7', 'ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7']
```

and I want to split these strings into 3 sublists, like this:

```
numerals = ['ii', 'vi', 'V', 'IV', 'I', 'V', 'IV', 'ii', 'vi', 'V', 'IV', 'I', 'V', 'IV']
chord_type=['min', 'min', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj','maj', 'min', 'min', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj','maj']
extentions=['7','7','', 'add9','add9','','7','7','7','','add9','add9','','7']
```

(As you can see, the roman numerals in capital letters correspond to 'maj' in chord type and in non-capital letters to 'min'. )

All the possible roman numerals in my case:

```
i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, vii, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII
```

Note that we don't need `M`, `C`, `L`, `X` .

I know I can extract or split numbers from letters in a string in Python, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825729/extract-number-from-string-in-python), but how can I extract roman numerals?

I thought about using something like *match* regex, but I'm confused on how to define those 7 roman numerals as these characters might occur again in the string.

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Have you tried to use a regular expression that matches roman numerals instead of `\d+`? (note that you do not need to match all possible roman numerals, only those from 1 to 7)

Comment: One thing you should start with is to get a list of all the `numerals`, perhaps just in lower case. You seem to be missing some. You need `i` .. `vii` for the seven notes of a scale.

Comment: what makes the "i" in `'min'` different than the "i" in `'vi7'`? In other words, is what you are trying to do *mathematically* feasible?

Comment: Can you enumerate all of the possible a) numerals, b) chord_types and c) extensions?

Comment: @Ma0: All the chords will start with `i` .. `vii` and `min` is optional. (Or so I thought).

Comment: What about the ending? Is it always there and is it always a single digit?

Comment: Share your code, what you did so far?

Comment: Aren't lower case major, or uppercase minor/diminshed invalid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If roman numeral is always first then you might do

```
import re
chords = ['ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7', 'ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7']
numerals = [re.match('[IiVv]+', i).group(0) for i in chords]
print(numerals)
```

output

```
['ii', 'vi', 'V', 'IV', 'I', 'V', 'IV', 'ii', 'vi', 'V', 'IV', 'I', 'V', 'IV']
```

Note that I used [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) as it does *Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string* and limited digits to existing in your example (rather than using all known i.e. `IiVvXxLlCcDdMm`).

Comment: Roman numerals can have letters other than `I` and `V`, including `C`, `L`, `M`, and `X`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen these are chords so there's no need to add C, L, M ,X

Comment: @C-Bk Well in that case, it _sounds_ like you might be right `:-)`

Comment: @Daweo wouldn't this also match invalid chords like `II` or `iv`?

Answer (score 2):

You can quite simply do this with the `.startswith` string method like so:

```
nummerals = ['i', 'ii', 'iii', 'iv', 'v', 'vi', 'vii', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII']
lst = ['ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7', 'ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7']


nummerals.sort(key=len, reverse=True)  # see note 1

res = [next(n for n in nummerals if y.startswith(n)) for y in lst]  # see note 2
print(res)  # -> ['ii', 'vi', 'V', 'IV', 'I', 'V', 'IV', 'ii', 'vi', 'V', 'IV', 'I', 'V', 'IV']
```

Notes

1. The original `nummerals` list has to be sorted by length (descending order) to make sure you match the biggest possible nummeral (`.startswith` for `'ii7'` would match both `'i'` and `'ii'` but you want the second one).
2. The above code can throw a `StopIteration` error. If you want to prevent that, provide a fallback value to `next`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses a somewhat complex regular expression which offers two advantages:

1. If the extension of a number looks like a part of an impossible roman number, for example `IV` and then `I`, a naive approach would consider the number `IVI` whereas my approach will only consider `IV` with `I` as the extension.
2. If you need to extend your application with larger numbers, this will work for very large numbers.

**Edit:** Obviously for chords, it might be useless to have bigger numbers, but who knows? Maybe you will update the way music works

The regular expression I use comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267405/11489704). I have modified it a tiny bit to make it work here.

```py
import re

l = ['ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7', 'ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7']

numerals = []
chord_type = []
extensions = []

roman_regex = '^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})'

for e in l:
    roman_search = re.search(roman_regex , e.upper())
    start = roman_search.start()
    end = roman_search.end()
    roman = e[start:end]

    numerals.append(roman)
    chord_type.append('maj' if roman[0].upper() == roman[0] else 'min')
    extensions.append(e[end:])
```

```sh
>>> print(numerals)
... print(chord_type)
... print(extensions)

['ii', 'vi', 'V', 'IV', 'I', 'V', 'IV', 'ii', 'vi', 'V', 'IV', 'I', 'V', 'IV']
['min', 'min', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj', 'min', 'min', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj', 'maj']
['7', '7', '', 'add9', 'add9', '', 'maj7', '7', '7', '', 'add9', 'add9', '', 'maj7']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

matcher = re.compile(r'([IiVv]+)(min|maj|)(.*)')

def parse_string(s):
    gs = matcher.findall(s)[0]
    if gs[1] == '':
        gs = (gs[0], 'maj' if gs[0].isupper() else 'min', gs[2])
    return gs
    
def parse_array(A):
    return [parse_string(chord) for chord in A]
    
parsed = parse_array(['ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7', 'ii7', 'vi7', 'V', 'IVadd9', 'Iadd9', 'V', 'IVmaj7'])

numerals, chord_type, extensions = zip(*parsed)

print(list(numerals))
print(list(chord_type))
print(list(extensions))
```

I employed the use of `re` for regex parsing, surely that's no problem.