# How can I only extract number from tags in Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath

```
hots = html.xpath('//*[@id="pl_top_realtimehot"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()')[1:]
```

The list I get from hots is including numbers and characters. How can I get numbers only in Xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that directly with XPath.
What you can do is to get the `hots` string and then to extract numbers from it.
You did not mention programming language you are using, so for example with Java you can do as following:

```java
String numberOnly= hots.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

How to do that with Python please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825729/extract-number-from-string-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! I am a beginner at python. Do you know how to do it with python?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I case you need more assistance - please let me know